# Do I need CouchDB per peer in hyperledger if there is only one orgnization

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

If I'm creating 4 peers in one namespace/org in Hyperledger, do I need to create separate CouchDB for each Peer? Like for for peer0-->CouchDB0, for peer1-->CouchDB1? **And why?**

Regards,
Vikas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, separate CouchDB is needed for each peer if CouchDB is chosen as the state DB. As for why, Fabric peer and a CouchDB has been designed to have a one-to-one relationship, and there is no guarantee that all the peers will have same state even though they are in the same org, For example, Peers in the same Org may subscribe to different channels, in which case their Ledger and State will be different.

Comment: Most of the info you need is explained here (in particular rich queries)  -> https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/couchdb_as_state_database.html Also (as you tagged hyperledger-composer) - you would need a CouchDB configured to be able to run Composer queries (if using Composer) - an example of which is shown here -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/queries